# How to write jest test for lightning-datatable LWC

Tags: javascript, unit-test, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lwc-jest

I'm populating the data table in the jest test successfully but when I try to select any row it comes up null which leads to this error **TypeError: dataTableRow.click is not a function**

this is from my test

```
.then(() => {
        const dataTableRow = element.getElementsByClassName("slds-checkbox");
        expect(dataTableRow).toBeTruthy();
        const test = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-primitive-cell-checkbox");
        dataTableRow.click();
      })
```

Also jest has this error from the lwc js file when testing if I comment out the dataTableRow.click();
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelectedRows' of null**
which is caused in my handleSubmit function

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // stop the form from submitting
    const fields = event.detail.fields;
    if (this.isSubmitable(fields)) {
      this.selectedAccounts = this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable").getSelectedRows();
```

Comment: Why are you testing a standard component?

Comment: because it's used in a lwc that needs code coverage which requires setting values in a table and selecting and verify data that is selected.

Comment: Should you not be mocking out this component? Basically you want to test your code, not Salesforce’s code...

Comment: That could work. Could you provide and example how to mock this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable").getSelectedRows(); this is the line that is used in the code to get the data from the the table that has been selected

Comment: This looks like it might help I'll give it a try https://books.google.com/books?id=wlu8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA512&lpg=PA512&dq=how+to+mock+this.template.querySelector(%22lightning-datatable%22).getSelectedRows();&source=bl&ots=k2JonNaQ-h&sig=ACfU3U34Z8Q2V1I2m_l7pj8raxXd0MccWA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM3I7uwMvrAhVCYjUKHf2gAxgQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20mock%20this.template.querySelector(%22lightning-datatable%22).getSelectedRows()%3B&f=false

Comment: The example from the above link helped. Thank you @PhilW for setting me on the right path.

Comment: Great. Can I suggest you turn your comment into an answer so future searches will find an answered question, and I can update it too :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer of this question can be found here:
[How to mock custom LWC components in JEST](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285094/how-to-mock-custom-lwc-components-in-jest?rq=1)

So you just need to mock the method from the datatable:

```js
    .then(() => {
        const dataTableRow = element.getElementsByClassName("slds-checkbox");
        expect(dataTableRow).toBeTruthy();
        dataTableRow.getSelectedRows = jest.fn().mockImplementation( () => { return ['yourRecordHere'] });
        const test = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-primitive-cell-checkbox");
        dataTableRow.click();
      })
```